# Changing \n into ARRAY values within another ARRAY

Tags: php, arrays

I have this ARRAY sent from a FORM

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
two
three
    [1] => hello
how
are
)
```

Since the values are sent via textarea from a form, it has line breakers, so I want to make change every 
 into a array field like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => one
            [1] => two
            [2] => three
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => hello
            [1] => how
            [2] => are
        )

)
```

This is what I have so far:

```
foreach ($array as &$valor) {   
    foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $valor) as $line){
    $arraynew[] = $line;
}
}
```

But I get this result

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => three
    [3] => hello
    [4] => how
    [5] => are
)
```

What am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: You are only assigning every split value to `$arraynew[]`, so of course they all “land” on the same level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each key in the POST array, pop a value onto the final array, with it's values containing an array whoses values represent each line in value of the POST array.

```
<?php
$data = array(
 0 => "one\ntwo\nthree", 
 1 => "hello\nhow\nare"
);

$final = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
  $row = preg_split('/\n/', $data[$i]);
  if(is_array($row)) {
    for($j = 0; $j < count($row); $j++) {
      $final[$i][] = $row[$j];
    }
  }
}

var_dump($final);

array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(3) {
    [0] =>
    string(3) "one"
    [1] =>
    string(3) "two"
    [2] =>
    string(5) "three"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(3) {
    [0] =>
    string(5) "hello"
    [1] =>
    string(3) "how"
    [2] =>
    string(3) "are"
  }
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/144809)

Comment: This work perfecly, I just change `$final[$i][] = $row[$j];` for `$final[$i][] = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $row[$j]));` so it removes the \r at the end of each line

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're really working too hard.

```
array_map(function($e) { return explode("\n", $e); }, $orig_array);
```

is all you need. You could use `preg_split` if you really want, but `explode` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this

```
 $array=array("one\ntwo\nthree","hello\nhow\nare");
 $arraynew=array();
 foreach ($array as &$valor) {   
 $arraynewtemp=array();
 foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $valor) as $line){
 $arraynewtemp[] = $line;
 }
 array_push($arraynew,$arraynewtemp);
 }

 var_dump($arraynew);
```

Will output

```
 array(2) {
 [0]=>
  array(3) {
  [0]=>
   string(3) "one"
  [1]=>
   string(3) "two"
  [2]=>
   string(5) "three"
   }
 [1]=>
  array(3) {
  [0]=>
   string(5) "hello"
  [1]=>
   string(3) "how"
  [2]=>
   string(3) "are"
 }
}
```

This should works